# BLoC state + freezed library with multiple fields

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, freezed, flutter-freezed

I created bloc with "on" handler where I request topics from API. I can control loading and error. I add the second "on" handler in bloc where I request top selected topic, and I want to work with the same bloc with topics to save this top selected topic near all topics:
`List<Topic> topics = [], Topic topSelected = TopSelected(...)` 
something like that

I created one more method in my state to upload this top selected topic and it was loaded well, but when I render data in my widget via `state.when` I face with error because I need to implement all state methods in the widget (render topSelected and topic) but I need only topSelected in my widget

[[image: WIDGET(https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FKuy.png)]]
[[image: STATE(https://i.stack.imgur.com/CF9wx.png)]]
[[image: EVENTS(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkcGv.png)]]
[[image: BLOC(https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkR7l.png)]

I tried to create on more method in my state but I faced with error in the widget. May be I can mark this methods as non required or a kind of it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm too late, but it will be helpful to others.
You can use `maybeWhen`, to use only specific conditions with default value in `orElse` parameter:

```dart
BlocBuilder<AuthCubit, QuizzesState>(
   builder: (context, state) {
      return state.maybeWhen(
         loading: () => Text('Loading'),
         orElse: () => Text('orElse'),
       );
    },
),
```